# Перевод любого файла в двоичный код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу реализовать в python перевод файла в двоичный код для последующий его обработки и нигде не могу найти об этом информацию. Кто ни будь знает как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Прям двоичный или удобнее будет hex?

Comment: прям в двоичный

Comment: Да, но как его в нём прочитать?

Comment: @Эникейщик Мое предположение в ответе. Думаю автор хочет посмотреть каждый бит в виде состояния 0 или 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('anyfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    print(' '.join(format(i, 'b') for i in f.read()))
```

В таком смысле?

Comment: пробел можно убрать, чтбо настоящий двоичный код был :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Хех, можно, но так удобнее воспринимать